# get element value on checkbox checked in Gridview?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with ItemTemplate( Checkbox and TextBox )

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNonTimeCard" runat="server">
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" onclick="return chkDelete_OnClick(this);"></asp:CheckBox>
       </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" CssClass="Width_2" format="Date" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,  "DataItem.DateWorked") %>' Description="Date on row ">                                        
            </asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

> I have written a JavaScript function to find a texDate value on click checkbox. But i dont' see get any value its returning control id "gvNonTimeCard_ctl03_txtDate"?

```
function chkDelete_OnClick(objCheckbox) {
 if (objCheckbox != null) {
     console.log("objCheckBox null");
     var val = document.getElementById(objCheckbox.id.replace("chkDelete", "txtDate")).id;       
 }
```

Comment: replace this line in you code var val = document.getElementById(objCheckbox.id.replace("chkDelete", "txtDate")).value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line in you code

```
var val = document.getElementById(objCheckbox.id.replace("chkDelete", "txtDate")).value;
```

Comment: I have another question. When my gird having more than 1 Row, below code returning a date value. When i have 1 row in a grid "date" is returning as null value?  foreach (GridViewRow row in gvNonEmployeeTimeCard.Rows)
            {
                
                deleteRow = Methods.SafeConvertToBool(((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkDelete")).Checked);
                date = Methods.SafeConvertToDate(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDate")).Text.Trim());